# Store session data, routes and controller in laravel problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, post, controller

**Controller**

**WelcomeController.php**

```php
public function storeSession(Request $request, $data){

    $request->session()->put('srcode','data.usr_name');
    echo "Session stored.";
        
    return 1;
        

}
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
<form id="login" action="{{ url('/')}}" method="POST" >
    @csrf
                    
</form>
               
<!-- insert script to add event-->
<script>
                    
    //create new instance
    var api = new API("key");
                    
    //initialize api
    var records = api.result;
    console.log(records);

    api.init(function(){
                            
        //attach click event to the button
        $("#btnShowLogin").click(function(){
            //show login window                                
            api.login({type:'student'},function(result){
                //check result
                if(result.error==0){
                                        
                    console.log("OK");

                    $.ajax({

                        url: '/session',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: result.details,
                                        
                        success: function(result){

                            if(result == 1){
                                                    
                                document.getElementById('login').submit();
                                console.log(result);

                            }
                         } 

                    });
                } 
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/session',[App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class, 'storeSession'])->name('session.store');
```

**Errors**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Accessing which route gives you the 404 error? Does the error provide any stack trace which shows which line in your code causes the error

Comment: public function storeSession(Request $request, $data){

This line from welcome controller, Sir.

Comment: I am new in Laravel and want to create session using the API that was given to me. I was informed to create session of login user instead of using database.

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to visit `/session` in the browser or when you click a button and ajax request is sent to the server? Have you tried running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::storeSession(), 1 passed in C:\Users\User\popuplogin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected`

This is the error I get. If I go to /session. I checked the error and brought me in this same line public function storeSession(Request $request, $data){.

Comment: Can you help me? I am having a hard time on this. Or should i use lightweight framework like Lumen/Slim/Sylex?

Comment: Please see the answer below and let me know it my understanding about what  you are trying to achieve is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method storeSession should be defined as

```php
class WelcomeController
{
    public function createSession(Request $request)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function storeSession(Request $request)
    {
        //$request->session()->put('srcode','data.usr_name');

        //Store the usr_name value from data received via (Post) ajax request
        $request->session()->put('srcode',$request->usr_name);
        echo "Session stored.";
        
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Routes:

```php
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
    ->group(function(){
        //Display the page with script which sends ajax request via Post
        Route::get('/session',[WelcomeController::class, 'createSession'])->name('session.create');

        //Handle the ajax request and store data in session
        Route::post('/session',[WelcomeController::class, 'storeSession'])->name('session.store');

    });
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try that. Can i email you? if ever i need some help?

Comment: @Luffy You can reach me via twitter or my site - both in my profile

Comment: Does the answer work as expected for you?

Comment: Which 'data' has been removed from the answer - can you pls explain?

Comment: I'm sorry I miss quite of the syntax on your code I thought the controller was the same from my codes because the $data was gone, sorry about that. But i do have a problem on this line `Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
    ->group(function{
`. Seems like unexpected {, expected (.

Comment: Oops... Typo here missing parenthesis function()  thanks for pointing out fixed it.

Comment: Can I reach you out later or maybe tomorrow? I can't reach you here because of lack of reputation. Hahaha. My bad.

Comment: That's okay. And if the answer helped you solve the issue in your question, pls remember to mark it as accepted for the benefit of subsequent newbie to laravel visitors